# Journey Activation - No longer creates an automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

When activating a new Journey with a schedule type of 'Run Now' or 'Recurring' the system used to automatically create an automation with the Journey. The automation name was the Journey name with a datestamp appended to the end, and the only step was the activity 'Journey Entry: Audience'

[image]

I am now noticing this automation is no longer being created for new Journeys. I used this automation as a fail-safe to manually inject contacts into Journeys past the initial scheduled date. Not the end of the world to do things differently going forward, but I'm just looking for confirmation this is the new expected behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in the article: [Unable to view Automations created from Journey Builder recurring or run once schedule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351603&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

> Prior to the October 2019 release, when you scheduled the Journey to run on a Recurring schedule, the Journey provided a link to the system-created Automation that manages the schedule for the journey. You could click on the link and access the Automation.
>
> With the October 2019 Release, system-created Automations resulting from setting a Journey Builder Recurring Schedule are no longer visible from the application. The Journeys will run based on the recurring schedule defined, as they did prior to this change.